# How to access force.com Rest Api from Site.com?

Tags: apex, javascript, api, rest, site.com

I need to call an authenticated Apex Rest API from Site.com page. The way I am trying is using Username-Password Oauth authorization flow, to get access token.

Below is the javascript code I am trying,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: {
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'client_secret': 'xxxxxxx',
            'username': 'xxx@xxxx.com',
            'password': '*******'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Successfully retrieved ' + response);
            //Other logic here
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log('Failed ' + response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
            //Other logic here
        }
    });
});
```

But when I preview the site page, I receive a Cross Domain Access error in the browser console,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'https://nikhil-demo-dev-ed--sitepreview.ap2.force.com' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

Does anybody have a solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: also have a looks at https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no way around calling that particular REST API?

Using the good ol ajax toolkit can be pretty versatile since you are on the Salesforce server.
  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm